# Error 451 when referencing powerpoint presentations and slides

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have inherited some code which uses **three global variables**

```
Global PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Global PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Global PPtSlides As PowerPoint.Slide
```

Later on in the code it uses them in the following way

```
Sub PasteTablesPPT(TargetText As String, PPTRange As Range)

Dim TargetSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

PPTApp.Activate

For Each PPtSlides In PPTPres.Slides               'Error on colleagues PC
    With PPtSlides.Shapes.Title.TextFrame
        If .HasText Then
            If UCase(.TextRange.Text) = UCase(TargetText) Then
                TargetNum = CInt(PPtSlides.SlideIndex)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
```

**On my PC this works as it should** i.e. it activates the open powerpoint application and then loops through each of the slides within that presentation.

However on my **colleagues PC, the runs into an error on the line I have flagged**. The specific error is **[Error 451](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278554.aspx)** and I think it's to do with PPtSlides not being recognized as part if PPtPres.Slides. Also in debug mode when I hover over **PPtSlides it says ="Nothing"**.

We have the same references check in VBA tools, could anyone shed some light on why this would work on my PC and not my colleagues?

EDIT:
The part where PPTPres is defined (in another sub and this is just an extract of that sub)

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set PPTApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    PPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations("Testing File")
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Are you using the same PPT file?

Comment: If you check the value of `PPtSlides` while the line is in yellow, it is normal that it says nothing as the line hasn't been executed yet. Though, can you **add the part were `PPTPres` is defined?** It is most probably coming from there. *And just a remark, to respect conventions, it'd be easier for understanding to have  `PPtSlide` instead of  `PPtSlides` as it for a single Slide and not the Collections.*

Comment: Same version of PowerPoint?

Comment: Yep, same version of PP and same file being used.

Comment: The error seems to be a collection based one, so was thinking it could be the .slides collection of the PPT, but not sure now :)

Comment: I don't know what is your Error handler doing, but generally, I use this to Get or Set an Application object. `On Error Resume Next:
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application"):
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application"):
On Error GoTo 0` Can you post error handler ErrHandler too?

Comment: The error handler just creates a powerpoint in case the user doesn't have the one called Testing File open. The users are myself and 4 other colleagues, so the code doesn't actually ever go through the error handler .

Answer (score 0):

In the sub PasteTablesPPT, try to declare PPtSlides as PowerPoint.Slide

```
dim PPtSlides as PowerPoint.Slide
```